# Getting an average from time that is in text form

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need to find the average time from a column. The time is currently in text format ie. 1 day 3 hours 3 minutes and 3 seconds so I cannot use an average formula.
How can I easily convert this into a format that I can find an average for the whole column?
I hope this makes sense.
Thanks

[image: data + formula]

Comment: What if there is no minutes? Would this show 0 minutes? Or skip that part? This would be easier in VBA

Comment: If there were no minutes it would show up as 0 minutes

Comment: What would the output look like?

Comment: the output would be in the original x days y hours z minutes v seconds format

Comment: What is in the formula bar when you click on A2?

Comment: "0 day 5 hours 35 minutes 1 seconds" - it is text pulled in from another system

Comment: Then My guess is that you have non breaking spaces instead of normal spaces.  Try this, in B2 put `=CODE(Mid(A2,2,1))` and tell me what it returns.

Comment: An error about one of more circular references

Comment: you put that in `B2` and got a circular reference?  that is not possible unless `A2` has a formula that refers to `B2`.  Copy paste the actual strings in the question, so I can copy paste.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read it properly. When I put it in B2 I got a "32"

Comment: I have no idea why you are getting that then.

Comment: no worries, thank you for your help

Answer (score 4):

one can use FILTERXML:

```
=INT(SUM(IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1:A6)," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(.,"&{"'day'","'hour'","'min'","'sec'"}&")]/preceding-sibling::*[1]")/{1,24,1440,86400},0))/COUNTA(A1:A6))&" day(s) "&TEXT(SUM(IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1:A6)," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(.,"&{"'day'","'hour'","'min'","'sec'"}&")]/preceding-sibling::*[1]")/{1,24,1440,86400},0))/COUNTA(A1:A6),"H \h\o\u\r\s m \m\i\n\u\t\e\s s \s\e\c\o\n\d\s")
```

Depending on ones version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I've changed the cell ranges but I seem to just be getting 0 days 0 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds. Any idea why?

Comment: not without seeing the data.  Can you edit your post to include a photo of the data mock up, showing the formula and results?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert those string to true date/time values:

```vb
t = " 1 day 3 hours 3 minutes and 3 seconds"
n = Split(Trim(t))
TotalTime = TimeSerial(n(0) * 24 + n(2), n(4), n(7))
' TotalTime -> 1899-12-31 03:03:03
```

These values can be averaged.

Finally, if you wish a time-formatted display, apply this function:

```vb
Public Function FormatHourMinuteSecond( _
  ByVal datTime As Date, _
  Optional ByVal strSeparator As String = ":") _
  As String
  
' Returns count of days, hours, minutes, and seconds of datTime
' converted to hours, minutes, and seconds as a formatted string
' with an optional choice of time separator.
'
' Example:
'   datTime: #10:03:55# + #20:01:24#
'   returns: 30:05:19
'
' 2014-06-17. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim strHour       As String
  Dim strMinuteSec  As String
  Dim strHours      As String
  
  strHour = CStr(Fix(datTime) * 24 + Hour(datTime))
  ' Add leading zero to minute and second count when needed.
  strMinuteSec = Right("0" & CStr(Minute(datTime)), 2) & strSeparator & Right("0" & CStr(Second(datTime)), 2)
  strHours = strHour & strSeparator & strMinuteSec
  
  FormatHourMinuteSecond = strHours
  
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `VBA` `UDF` solution which is dependant on your string always having the following format:

```
x day y hours z minutes and n seconds
```

---

When cell format is `[hh]:mm:ss` this converts

`1 day 3 hours 3 minutes and 3 seconds` to `27:03:03`

This format can easily be averaged to give you your final answer

---

```
Public Function cst_time(Target As Range) As Double

Dim Temp, days As Long, hours As Double, minutes As Double, seconds As Double

Temp = Split(Target, " ")
days = Temp(0)
hours = Temp(2) / 24
minutes = Temp(4)
seconds = Temp(7) / 60

cst_time = days + hours + ((seconds + minutes) / (24 * 60))

End Function
```